# How to send notification between Apps using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that needs to send data (single integer) to another phone which has the same app. This data would pop up as a notification on the other phone.

I have been able to use FCM to send notifications to the app by using the console. However, I do that manually by sending the message. I now need to send data from the app itself to the same app on the other phone. I was not able to figure out how FCM can do this in the documentation.

I realize that I need to some how get the tokens from one phone's app and have the other app listen for any notification. The tokens are pretty large, so I don't think I should get the user to type in the tokens to listen for notifications from the other app. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: I am not using an app server. I was aiming to just accomplish this simple notification from one app to the other just using FCM

Comment: Don't you see the problem? In order to use FCM, you need to somehow communicate the registration ID from one device to another. But if you have the means to do that, you can use the same means to transmit the message itself. This looks like an XY problem (where Y=FCM). What's the underlying business case?

Comment: I am doing this as a learning experience. I have an app that tracks the breathing rate of a user. If the rate goes up or below a certain threshold, I want it to be able to notify someone else. Hence, I was looking into something that might already have it prebuilt.

Comment: Send an e-mail or an SMS to someone else :) That's the prebuilt method.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a learning experience, seamless experience/user friendliness is probably not much of a concern. If you don't have a central server and are not planning to have one, enable the standard "Share" interface on the token, and let users send it around by any supported means of human-to-human communication - SMS, e-mail, WhatsApp, anything.

On the target device, let them paste it into the app UI.

The logic to invoke the standard "Share..." UI goes:

```
String TheToken; //Comes from the FCM registration callback...
startActivity(
    Intent.createChooser(
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        .setType("text/plain")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TheToken), ""));
```

This snippet assumes it's in an `Activity` method, i. e. the current `this` object is a `Context` instance.

In a real life application, you'd probably want a central server.

Another avenue would be - there are some options that rely on physical proximity. Read up on Network Service Discovery (NSD); that's a means for an application to find other instances of the same application running on devices *on the same Wi-Fi*. Internally, it's the Zeroconf/Bonjour protocol, facilitated by DNS multicast. This kind of logic is more involved; you'd have to spin up your own network server on a custom port.

Other options for communication with **nearby** devices include Bluetooth PAN and Near Field Communication (NFC). I have no experience with either of those, sorry. I just know they exist :)